# JSOM - add metadata to several columns when file is uploaded

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jsom

I found a [piece of code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery#code-example-2-upload-a-file-in-the-same-domain-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery) online that uploads a document to a document library and also updates the file name with what the user enters in a text box.  It works perfectly.  The challenge that I have is modifying the code so that I can update several columns(metadata) when the file is uploaded.

```
'use strict';

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

// Check for FileReader API (HTML5) support.
if (!window.FileReader) {
    alert('This browser does not support the FileReader API.');
}

});

 // Upload the file.
// You can upload files up to 2 GB with the REST API.
 function uploadFile() {

// Define the folder path for this example.
var serverRelativeUrlToFolder = 'Shared Documents';

// Get test values from the file input and text input page controls.
var fileInput = jQuery('#getFile');
var newName = jQuery('#displayName').val();
//alert("fileInput: "+fileInput);
//alert("newName: "+newName);
// Get the server URL.
var serverUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;

// Initiate method calls using jQuery promises.
// Get the local file as an array buffer.
var getFile = getFileBuffer();
getFile.done(function (arrayBuffer) {

    // Add the file to the SharePoint folder.
    var addFile = addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer);
    addFile.done(function (file, status, xhr) {
        // Get the list item that corresponds to the uploaded file.
        var getItem = getListItem(file.d.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri);
        getItem.done(function (listItem, status, xhr) {

            // Change the display name and title of the list item.
            var changeItem = updateListItem(listItem.d.__metadata);
            changeItem.done(function (data, status, xhr) {
                alert('file uploaded and updated');
            });
            changeItem.fail(onError);
        });
        getItem.fail(onError);
    });
    addFile.fail(onError);
});
getFile.fail(onError);

// Get the local file as an array buffer.
function getFileBuffer() {
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
        deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
    }
    reader.onerror = function (e) {
        deferred.reject(e.target.error);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput[0].files[0]);
    return deferred.promise();
}

// Add the file to the file collection in the Shared Documents folder.
function addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer) {

    // Get the file name from the file input control on the page.
    var parts = fileInput[0].value.split('\\');
    var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

    // Construct the endpoint.
    var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
            "{0}/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/files" +
            "/add(overwrite=true, url='{2}')",
            serverUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, fileName);
            console.log("fileCollectionEndpoint "+fileCollectionEndpoint);

    // Send the request and return the response.
    // This call returns the SharePoint file.
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
        type: "POST",
        data: arrayBuffer,
        processData: false,
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
        }
    });
}

// Get the list item that corresponds to the file by calling the file's ListItemAllFields property.
function getListItem(fileListItemUri) {

    // Send the request and return the response.
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: fileListItemUri,
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
    });
}

// Change the display name and title of the list item.
function updateListItem(itemMetadata) {

    // Define the list item changes. Use the FileLeafRef property to change the display name. 
    // For simplicity, also use the name as the title. 
    // The example gets the list item type from the item's metadata, but you can also get it from the
    // ListItemEntityTypeFullName property of the list.
    var body = String.format("{{'__metadata':{{'type':'{0}'}},'FileLeafRef':'{1}','Title':'{2}'}}",
        itemMetadata.type, newName, newName);

    // Send the request and return the promise.
    // This call does not return response content from the server.
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: itemMetadata.uri,
        type: "POST",
        data: body,
        headers: {
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-length": body.length,
            "IF-MATCH": itemMetadata.etag,
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
        }
    });
}
}

 // Display error messages. 
 function onError(error) {
    console.log(error.responseText);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit this line:

```
var body = String.format("{{'__metadata':{{'type':'{0}'}},'FileLeafRef':'{1}','Title':'{2}'}}",
    itemMetadata.type, newName, newName);
```

Into the one that you needs. E.g:

```
var body = String.format("{{'__metadata':{{'type':'{0}'}},'FileLeafRef':'{1}','Title':'{2}', 'YourMEta1', '{3}', 'YourMetadata2', '{4}'}}",
    itemMetadata.type, newName, newName, meta1value, meta2value);
```

Comment: I get the following error: "The property 'Project_0020_Number' does not exist on type 'SP.Data.Shared_x0020_DocumentsItem'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type."  I'm using the internal name of the column metadata I'm trying to update.

Comment: I figured it out.  My internal name was missing a character.  'Project_x0020_Number'.  Thanks a bunch for your help.